# use expect to automate ssh keypair generation

Tags: bash, automation, expect

I want to automate command `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. What's unique is the command will print out different text under different conditions. For example, if it is the first time, it will output `enter passphrase` and `enter passphrase again`. otherwise, it will prompt with `Overwrite (y/n):` . How to handle this in `expect`.

I have tried using pattern action pair, like

> expect "enter passphrase" {send "\r"} \
>
> ```
>    "Overwrite (y/n): " {send "n\r"}
> ```

However, it only handles one prompt at a time; how can I handle the prompt `enter passphrase again`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exp_continue` may help you with this:

```
expect {
    "Overwrite (y/n)?" { send "n\r" ; exp_coninue }
    "Enter passphrase" { send "\r" ; exp_coninue }
    "passphrase again:" { send "\r" }
}
```